# c# ToCharArray assembly reference missing

Tags: c#

```
string random = "all can struggle quickly better way";

char[] charArray = charArray.ToCharArray();
```

I have tried to add reference but I don't know how to add it

So please tell me how to remove this error and how to add assembly reference for

```
ToCharArray();
```

Comment: You mean `random.ToCharArray()` perhaps.

Answer (score 5):

replace

```
char[] charArray = charArray.ToCharArray();
```

with

```
char[] charArray = random.ToCharArray();
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add:

```
using System;
```

But your code is also wrong, it should be:

```
string random = "all can struggle quickly better way";

char[] charArray = random.ToCharArray();
```